# Is there a simple way to convert {a,b,c} to a,b,c?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to use:

```
Composition[G][x]
```

in the elements of the following list:

```
j = {{a, b, c}, {c, b, a}};
```

That is, I could do:

```
Table[Composition[j[[n]]][x], {n, 1, 2}]
```

which produces:

```
{{a, b, c}[x], {c, b, a}[x]}
```

but `Composition` doesn't seem to work with lists. I can't evaluate `Composition[{a,b,c}][x]`; it accepts only `Composition[a,b,c][x]`.

Is there a simple way to convert `Composition[{a,b,c}]` to `Composition[a,b,c]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
lis = {a, b, c}
Composition[Sequence @@ lis][x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Doesn't just `Composition @@ lis` work just fine?

Comment: @LSpice yes, and it needs to be enclosed by parentheses before applying to an argument, e.g. `(Composition @@ lis)[x]`

Comment: @polfosol or just `x // Composition @@ lis `

Answer (score 17):

[`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) is designed for this purpose:

```
Apply[Composition][{a, b, c}][x]
(*  a[b[c[x]]]  *)
```

Or

```
Apply[Composition, {a, b, c}][x]
```

Comment: Shorthand for `Apply` is `@@`. E.g. `(Composition @@ {a,b,c})[x]` or `x // Composition @@ {a,b,c}`.

Comment: @Džuris Yep, I usually use `@@`. Except, a personal preference, I dislike parentheses, which led me to avoid `@@` in these situations.  With command completion, the length of typing is about the same, and no parentheses feels easier to type & read for me.

Answer (score 13):

With:

```
alist = {a, b, c}
```

A variant using `Fold` could be:

```
Fold[Composition, alist][x]
```

> a[b[c[x]]]

Another variant using `ComposeList` could be:

```
ComposeList[Reverse@alist, x]
```

> {x, c[x], b[c[x]], a[b[c[x]]]}

from which the last item can be extracted.

Comment: `x // Fold[Composition] /@ {{a, b, c}, {c, b, a}} // Through` shows how naturally `Fold` and `Composition` can express the solution to OP's problem. Or `myFuncList = Fold[Composition] /@ {{a, b, c}, {c, b, a}};`
which can be used later, either as individual functions or in `Through[myFuncList[x]]`

Comment: A variation of this solution is `Fold[ReverseApplied[Construct], x, Reverse@{a, b, c}]`.

Answer (score 5):

Since no one seems to have answered how to `Apply` `Composition` to a `List` like `j` given by OP, here it is:

```
Composition[##][x]&@@#&/@j
```

> {a[b[c[x]]],c[b[a[x]]]}

Comment: Or `Composition[##][x]&@@@j` if always a list of lists of functions. :)

Comment: A simpler version is: `#[x]& /@ Composition@@@j`