# Turning list of functions into composition of functions

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a Mathematica-esque way to apply set of functions in a sequence? IE `apply[{f,g,h},x]` that produces result equivalent to `f@g@h@x`

My current workaround

```
apply[{}, x_] := x;
apply[{f_}, x_] := f@x;
apply[l_, x_] := First[l]@apply[Rest[l], x];
```

Comment: [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)? `Composition[f, g, h][x, y]` returns `f[g[h[x, y]]]`. There is also [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html); `RightComposition[f, g, h][x, y]` returns `h[g[f[x, y]]]`.

Comment: Have you seen [this previous thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258523)?

Comment: yes, Composition is what I was looking for, thanks!