# How to use RightComposition efficiently in the context of one-liners?

Tags: expression-manipulation, code-review

I find myself recently writting, more often than not, code that makes heavy use of [*RightComposition*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) eg.

```
expr//f/*g/*h
```

It is relatively straightforward to first operate on `expr` with `f` then apply `g` on the result and so on with operators like `h` etc.

It gets cumbersome, however, to operate on complicated expressions *eg*. `head1[expr1,head2[expr2]]`; also, performing contrived operations gets progressively hard to handle.

I find that the major drawback of writing *one-liners* like that, hits hardest when subsequent operations need input consumed by operators applied earlier on.

To tackle this problem I find myself making heavy use of [*Through*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) eg.

```
expr//(Through[{Identity,f}[#]]&)/*Apply[g]
```

In the code snippet, `g` needs both `expr` and `f[expr]` as input and this is where `Through` comes in handy.

Carrying intermediate results to subsequent operators, in that fashion, proves equally cumbersome *esp*. when the chain of operations is long.

Trying to find a compromise that allows me to keep writting *one-liners* that are relatively easy to maintain, debug and help mitigate their downsides I came up with `chainList`:

```
chainList[expr_, fs__] := Fold[Join[#1,{#2@@#1}]&, {expr}, {fs}]
```

`chainList` resembles [*FoldList*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) in that it returns a list of intermediate results *eg*.

```
chainList[x,f,g,h]
```

evaluates to

```
{x,f[x],g[x,f[x]],h[x,f[x],g[x,f[x]]]}
```

I have experimented with different implementations of `chainList` but I can't seem to find an implementation that performs *faster* than the one presented above.

It is true that speed is not so much of an issue for most of my practical needs as I rarely chain more than 5-7 operators in a line and operations are mostly structural modifications of the expressions involved; however I would like to find out if there's a better approach to handling one-liners and also if `chainList` can be improved.

Comment: "I rarely chain more than 5-7 operators in a line" - doesn't that hamper readability and maintainability of your code?

Comment: @MarcoB when I have to chain many operators, yes it does; not having to worry about their input makes things somewhat easier

Comment: Perhaps this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258523/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-a-b-c-to-a-b-c/258534#258534) could give you some pointers.

Comment: @Syed thanks, [`ComposeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComposeList.html) looks promising, also I didn't know [`ReverseApplied`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseApplied.html) was a thing

Comment: I never understood what is the purpose of /* in that context. Why not `expr//f//g//h` ?

Comment: Also for `g[x,f[x]]` I would do `x// g[#,f@#]&` which is easier to understand and read in my opinion. Readability is important for the me in 2 years that has to read the code again.

Comment: If you rather not use # then you could use `x // {Identity, f} // Through //Apply[g]` but that is more adapted to writing the code in a column using the code cell style

Answer (score 4):

I also enjoy using "shell pipe" programming style with RightComposition. Though I prefer to use "one-columners" rather than "one-liners" because it is easy to comment.
Compare

```
x // f/*g/*h
```

With

```
x // RightComposition[
  (* f is doing this*)
  f,
  (* g is doing that*)
  g,
  (* h wraps it up*)
  h
  ]
```

To answer your question, this format makes it natural to use pure functions to keep track of intermediate results and closures to use them . Here for instance, the intermediate result of f ("interf") is used in the function h.

```
x // RightComposition[
  (* f is doing this *)
  f,
  (* we keep the intermediary result of f*)
  interf |-> interf // RightComposition[
     (* g is doing that *)
     g,
     (* h wraps it up *)
     OperatorApplied[h,{1,2}][interf]
     ]
  ]
```

which give `h[f[x], g[f[x]]]`. [OperatorApplied](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html) is flexible. For instance, if the (usually built-in) function h requires that you must compute `h[g[f[x]],f[x]]`, Simply use `OperatorApplied[h,{2,1}][interf]` instead of  `OperatorApplied[h,{1,2}][interf]`

I have never used so far this pattern on time or memory sensitive computations, but I would suppose that a functional language like the Wolfram Language would handle it efficiently.